# Converting double format to proper timedate with R

Tags: r

```
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2018-09-10"
> Sys.timezone()
[1] "Asia/Jakarta"
> library(readr)
> CDR_20180820111 <- read_delim("projects/R/CDR/CDR_20180820111.txt", 
+     "|", escape_double = FALSE, col_types = cols(A_IMEI = col_character(), 
+         A_IMSI = col_character(), A_P_NUM = col_character(), 
+         B_IMSI = col_character(), B_P_NUM = col_character(), 
+         CLSTR_ID = col_character(), DRTN = col_character(), 
+         INTCCT_ID = col_character(), STRT_DTTM = col_double()), 
+     trim_ws = TRUE)
```

R suggested and have taken the value as double format (`2.018082e+13`) instead of `YYYY-MM-DD` as formatted of `Sys.Date()`.

Here is the result when I changed `col_double()` format to `col_character()`

`20180820173410`, expected to be `YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS`

Any suggestion and feedback is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Aan Kasman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract time then you can do:

```
test <- "20180820173410"
strptime(test, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

where `format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"` tells you that the original string is in the form of `YearMonthDayHourMinuteSecond`

To extract date you can equivalently do:

```
as.Date(test, format = "%Y%m%d")
```

If you would like to see the time in the format of 
`YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS` you can do:

```
format(strptime(test, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S"), "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
```

The conversion to time works regardless of whether your original input is string or numeric.

Comment: It worked. Thanks much @ira , @vlad really appreciated it. Also I did changed R environment to ``options(digits=22)``

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best if you import dates as strings (or perhaps even numbers) and then convert them to date format. I would suggest using `lubridate`, which has a set of very easy to use functions to convert values to date or date-time. For example:

```
ymd_hms(20180820173410) # If date stored as as number
[1] "2018-08-20 17:34:10 UTC"

ymd_hms('20180820173410') # If date stored as string
[1] "2018-08-20 17:34:10 UTC"
```

As you probably figured out, `ymd_hms` is for dates in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format (month can also be written using three-letter abbreviations). You also have functions such as `mdy`, `dmy` and their date-time counterparts.